# Maximize the amount of money you pick up as you travel through an array

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem, maximization

Given an array of integers for example, [1 4 3 2 9 8 7 6]
Each integer represents an amount of money you can pick up.
You are traveling through the array, and you can pick up the money.
Every time you pick up some money, you must travel another X amount (minInterval) in order to pick up more money. - that is you must wait X travels in order to pick up any more money. What is the maximum amount of money you can pick up given the minInterval.

note: each travel is essentially just moving to the next index.
you want to maximize the value of the money you pick up.

for example, if the minimum interval is 4 an optimal path would be,
[image]

What is a good algorithm to accomplish this?
It's basically an optimization problem.

Comment: I'd recommend to start with recursive approach: Choose the best variant using the first item and omitting it. In the first case recursive call should use X-th item

Comment: Try solving subproblems of the form "Maximise the amount of money *given that you start at position i*", using the already-computed solutions to other subproblems of the same form.

Comment: This is an classic knapsack problem variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the dynamic programming to solve the problem.
traverse the array from the last element to first,then you will have two choices for each element:

1.choose the current element ,transit from the i+x th element `dp[i]=dp[i+x]+a[i]`

2.don't choose the current element,transit from `dp[i+1]`,which means the max value you can get from interval `[i+1,n]`

then you can get:`dp[i]=max(dp[i+1],dp[i+x]+a[i])`

so:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,x;

    cin>>n>>x;
    vector<int> a(n+1);
    vector<int> dp(n+1+x);

    for(int i=1;i<=n;++i) cin>>a[i];

    for(int i=n;i>=1;--i){
        dp[i]=max(dp[i+1],dp[i+x]+a[i]);
    }

    cout<<dp[1]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense!!!

Comment: idk if this is asking too much, but how would you go about finding the positions chosen?

Comment: well,of course we don't know what positions to choose,that's why we use dynamic programming to solve it!As i said above,for each position,we can either choose it or not,if we choose it,then positions in interval `[i+1,i+x]` will can't be choose,so the best anwser is `dp[i+x]+a[i]`,and if we don't choose it,then positions in interval `[i+1,n]` can all be chosen,since `dp[i]` means the max value we can get if choose some positions from interval `[i,n]`, the best anwser is `dp[i+1]`,then compare the value between `dp[i+x]+a[i]` and `dp[i+1]`,the max one is what we want for the current position.

Comment: I've implemented the code you supplied in java. I basically want to be able to return the chosen positions. I'm having a hard time doing that.

Comment: There are 2 ways. The easiest is to make `dp[]` an array of *pairs*, where the first element of each pair is the score (as before) and the second is the position you came from to get that score. Then after computing the full matrix, you can start tracing forwards from `dp[0]`, following these "came from" pointers to recover an actual solution. This is called "traceback" since conceptually you start from the *end* (we computed `dp[0]` last) and trace backwards.